# How can I parse subpages of another website in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm creating a third-party web application of Last.fm and I'm having an issue with getting info about certain artist from them.

I have a method that parses data about some #{artist} from JSON:

artists_helper.rb

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

module ArtistsHelper

def about(artist)
    artist = "?"
    url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=#{artist}&api_key=f5cb791cfb2ade77749afcc97b5590c8&format=json"
    uri = URI(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    JSON.parse(response)
end

end
```

If I change '?' to the artist name in that method I can successfully parse info about artist from JSON file of that artist. But for when I go the page e.g. http://localhost:3000/artists/Wild+Nothing I need the method 'about(artist)' to get the value 'Wild+Nothing' and parse the data for Wild Nothing from Last.fm's JSON file.

How can I tell the method 'about' that what stands after http://localhost:3000/artists/ is the required value?

Answer (score 0):

In the routes, have a get route name that accepts a variable

```
get 'artists/:name', to: 'artists#about'
```

In the artists controller, have an about function:

```
def about
  artist = params[:name]
  url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=#{artist}&api_key=f5cb791cfb2ade77749afcc97b5590c8&format=json"
  uri = URI(url)
  response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  response = JSON.parse(response)

  render json: response
end
```

and we are good to go to display the json on the view.

If you need the param in the helper, just pass `params[:name]` to the helper as a parameter.

```
about(param[:name]) #wherever you are calling this method in the controller or view

def about(artist)
  url = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=#{artist}&api_key=f5cb791cfb2ade77749afcc97b5590c8&format=json"
  uri = URI(url)
  response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  JSON.parse(response)
end
```